# Tate's definition of residues

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables

In http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1968_4_1_1_149_0.pdf, Tate defines residues on a curve over an arbitrary field as a trace of some commutator. What is the intuition for the definition? If I knew the definition of a residue in complex analysis what might lead me to think about traces of commutators?

Comment: I haven't read the whole article so I must be missing something but I don't understand the definition. Could you at least explain the definition more thoroughly? If I plug in $f=x^{-1}$ and $g=x$ i get zero for the commutator but still $res(x^{-1}dx)=1$ (or 2$\pi$i i guess depending on convention perhaps). something's wrong with my interpretation obviously.

Comment: @SaalHardali: There is no good convention under which that residue should be $2\pi i$ or $-2\pi i$ (which cannot be intrinsically distinguished from $2\pi i$ by algebraic means and so cannot be the output of an intrinsic construction that doesn't involved it as input).

Answer (score 14):

Residues satisfy $$\operatorname{res}_x(fdg) + \operatorname{res}_x(gdf) = \operatorname{res}_x(d (fg)) =0$$

which tells you that they are antisymmetric, and many antisymmetric pairings in math arise from commutators.

Usually I find the best way to get intuition for these things is to calculate them explicitly for $z^n , n \in \mathbb Z$. I don't think it's too hard to calculate this trace definition for $z^n$, and see how it gets you the correct answer. Then linearity does the rest. But I'm not sure how much that will help explain how someone could think of it.

Comment: At least superficially, in a docile situation (e.g., finite-dimensional or trace-class or ...) the trace of a skew-symmetric thing such as a commutator would be $0$. So I think there must be a further idea to make this work... but I don't claim to know what it is. Can you clarify, from your viewpoint?

Comment: @paulgarrett I don't know how much to say, other than 1) we're not in a docile situation, and 2) in fact the operators we are working with are not defined uniquely, but they are well-defined up to operators whose composition has finite-dimensional image, so exactly this argument shows that the trace of the commutator of the discrepancy term vanishes and thus the commutator is well-defined. This reminds me a lot of cohomology, where a function vanishing on n-cochains is a prerequisite for being well-defined on n+1-cocycles.

Comment: Ah, well-defined up to docile things... answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Trace defines 2 cocycle for these infinite matrices. If you exp to group you get tame symbol. And reciprocity for it - Kac Arbarello DeConchini. People around  Parshin wanna do this in  higher dimensions...

Answer (score 12):

I don't have a conceptual answer, but here is what you get by tracing through Tate's definitions.
Let $V$ be the vector space of Laurent series in $t$ and $A$ the subspace of power series.
We will work with linear operators $\phi: V \to V$, which we think of as $\infty \times \infty$ matrices with rows and columns labeled by $\mathbb{Z}$.
We will often divide these infinte $4$ blocks. For example, the condition that $\phi(A) \subseteq A$ says that $\phi$ has block form $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} \ast & 0 \\ \ast&\ast \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.

We can represent Tate's ring $E$ with ideals $E_1$,$E_2$ and $E_0$ visually as follows:
$$
E = \begin{pmatrix} \ast & 0' \\ \ast & \ast \end{pmatrix} \qquad
E_1 = \begin{pmatrix}  0' &  0' \\ \ast & \ast \end{pmatrix} $$
$$E_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \ast &  0' \\ \ast &  0' \end{pmatrix} \qquad
E_0 = E_1 \cap E_2 = \begin{pmatrix}  0' &  0' \\ \ast &  0' \end{pmatrix} $$
where $0'$ means ``confined to finitely many rows".

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be Laurent series and write $f$ and $g$ for the operations of multiplication by $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. Let $f_1$ and $g_1$ be approximations with $f_1$, $g_1 \in E_1$ and $f \equiv f_1$, $g \equiv g_1 \bmod E_2$. Tate's claim is that $\mathrm{Tr}\ [f_1, g_1] = \mathrm{Res} (fdg)$.

Let's check for $f(t)=t^a$, $g(t)=t^b$, and one particular choice of $f_1$, $g_1$. Multiplication by $t^c$ is given by the matrix
$$M(c)_{ij} =  \begin{cases} 1 & i=j+c \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
We choose the approximation
$$S(c)_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq i=j+c \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
In other words, we take $M(c)$ and change all elements in the top blocks to $0$.

We note that $S(a)S(b) - S(b) S(a)$ has finitely many nonzero entries, so it makes sense to take its trace. Those entries lie on the diagonal $i=j+a+b$, so the trace is zero if $a+b \neq 0$. In the case $a+b=0$, I compute $\mathrm{Tr}\ [ S(-b), S(b) ] = b$. So we have
$$\mathrm{Tr}\ [S(a),S(b)] = \left\{ \begin{matrix} b & a+b=0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right\} = \mathrm{Res} {\Big(} x^a d(x^b) {\Big)}$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks David! While not a an answer I had hoped for, I was happy to see this.